# Laravel Error: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::post('posts/delete/{id}', 'PostController@destroy');
```

**Error:**

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 233

Comment: is this name of your method destroy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
Route::delete('posts/delete/{id}', 'PostController@destroy');
```